# Java compile times on two nearly identical machines

Tags: java, performance, compilation, virtual-machine

I'm trying to determine what might be causing Java to compile much slower on one of two almost identical setups. I am building the exact same code (under cvs) on a Fedora VM on each machine.

Machine 1:
    - Host OS: Windows 10 64b
    - Host Ram: 12 GB
    - Processor: Xeon 3530 Quad core @ 2.8 GHz
    - VM: Fedora 20 64b
    - VM Ram: 4 GB

Machine 2:
    - Host OS: Windows 10 64b
    - Host Ram: 8 GB
    - Processor: Xeon 3565 Quad core @ 3.2 GHz
    - VM: Fedora 20 64b
    - VM Ram: 2 GB

The compile time for the same code on machine 1 is almost 2x machine 2 despite having more ram. On both machines the host OS is installed on a standard spinning HD and the VM image stored on a SSD drive. The SSD drives are very similar but different brands. Is the difference caused by the difference in processor speed, SSD speed or something else?

**Edit: Solved, different versions of jdk**

Both VMs are using 1 cpu core. The faster machine is using jdk 1.6.0_33 and the slower machine is using 1.7.0_79.

Comment: you sure the vms are configured identically? same number of sockets/cores assigned to each?

Comment: Have you tried to monitor (with top etc.) how much cpu/hard drive is used by javac in both cases? Are you running the same version of javac?

Comment: what compilation are you talking about? Compiling the JVM from sources? Or JIT compilers when running a java application? Or compiling .java files into bytecode?

Comment: Compiling .java files with javac